# Where did Molly go?

Tags: discussion

Being an irregular regular on Super User, I know most of the crew which are also usually the most knowledgeable ones, and the first on the scene, when it comes to answering questions.

Lately, I haven't seen Molly answering any, and upon checking the user list I find her name missing. It isn't strange for a user to go away, but I find it somewhat unusual in this case, since she was one of the highest "ranking" ones on Super User.

Is she gone for good? Anyone?

Comment: This might be the first Meta question that has a dupe on Yahoo Answers: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091218063021AAgKVGw

Comment: @balpha: Sick 'n wrong, man :)

Comment: @NlfE - get a life. And what is that before your exclamation mark ?

Comment: @balpha - please restrain yourself from spamming the board.

Comment: Not for the first time, I wish I could up-vote an edit...

Comment: I did not understand the joke about the edit :(

Comment: My Molly lies over the websphere, my Molly lies over the tubes, my Molly no longers posts SU, please HTTP Molly to me!

Comment: @Downvoter - Most people pass over it, but it really bugs the fo'shizzle out of others: `"Is she gone for good ? Anyone ?"` vs `"Is she gone for good? Anyone?"`

Comment: @Polly: rhythm - good, rhyme - fail

Comment: Google cache of her user page shows that the bio was "Please delete me!" and the website was http://www.romlist.com/end/ (if down, here's the internet archive version: http://web.archive.org/web/20080105032230rn_1/www.romlist.com/end/ I don't know if the website changed, or if that was what she had in there previously.  The google cache of her userpage is http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:http://superuser.com/users/7244/molly which shows she was around at least on March 6th.  Of course all her old data was already released via the ccwiki data dump for February 2010 and prior data dumps.

Comment: @Pollyanna - personally, I find the innability of natural english speakers to express themselves in proper(!) english much more annoying than spaces before punctuation marks. Please, what is "fo'shizzle" - is that even a word ? You know, an english word ? (I don't count that language americans speak as english. Not for a long time now.).

Comment: @Idigas: as a good American, I am adept at just skipping over words I don't recognize, perhaps mentally substituting another word ("it really bugs the **pancakes** out of others")... But broken spacing makes it more difficult to scan a block of text (is that the end of a sentence, or is he just inserting symbols at random?)

Comment: I speak Spanish and it bothers even me. Punctuation marks are universal (and thus, the space before them universally annoying), words and expressions come and go, they come and go with the wind

Comment: @Shog9 - fair enough. (pancakes ?! Oh, why'd you have to say pancakes? Now I'm hungry again :-)) As far as broken spacing goes, I put space only in front of "?" I think. Don't know why, in my language it is tolerated, I believe in some other I speak as well, and find it very hard to change that habit. However, I should note that users on this site are the only ones ever that noticed that, and bragged about it. I'm not sure there is even an official rule for that in english. Besides, if you can ignore incorrect (even, non existant!!) words and skip over them, or substitute them, then

Comment: you can surely easily do so for that one blank as well. Words carry meaning, and are as such, of much higher importance than punctuation.

Comment: Funny thing about that... Words are *supposed* to carry meaning, but most folks use an awful lot of meaningless (or at least superfluous) words in actual conversation. In my experience, it is possible to ignore at least half of what someone's saying, so long as you pay attention to tone and inflection. Of course, text doesn't carry much in the way of tone *or* inflection... hence the importance of punctuation.

Comment: @Shog9 - I must disagree. First, words do (not "supposed to", but do(!)) carry meaning. Second, the fact that someting is superfluous does not make it meaningless. Third, it is hard to guess someone's tone, expecially to non native speakers of the language, and therefore, even the greater need for proper usage of the language. Besides, tone without content is meaningless per se.

Comment: And last, in my somewhat old english reference book, there is a rule about a blank after a comma, but nothing after/before a full stop/exclamation... so it must be a computer users thing. Probably those "space/blank hunting" python 'fellas.

Comment: Clicking on one of her posts as listed in google's cache, e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/55865/windows-7-search-broken, shows that her account is now deleted.

Comment: @Idigas: "fo`shizzle" is a corruption of "for sure" (certainly, without a doubt). Not that knowing this will help you understand Adam's comment; he might as well have written "waffles" or "abracadabra" - the word serves only to contribute a sense of whimsy (if that...)

Comment: @Shog9 - "Adam's comment" - Adam ?

Comment: @Idigas: "Adam" is short for "Pollyanna" - it's an Americanism...

Comment: @Shog9 - I see. But, isn't "PollyANNA" a girls name, in contrast to "Adam" ?

Comment: Yes - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollyanna

Comment: Well, in this case it depends on the boy having already been given (or taken on...) a girl's name...

Comment: People who enjoy English also enjoy correct placement of punctuation. And that means no space before exclamation marks or fullstops.

Comment: @random - Fair enough. I'll keep it in mind. From now on, to anyone who uses proper english when conversing with me, I'll extend the courtesy by not putting blanks before punctuation marks.

Answer (score 9):

Molly requested to have her account deleted, and after a cooling down period and an in depth discussion with her by Jeff and the Super User moderators she decided to have her account removed. She is welcome back at any time.

She is the first high reputation user I am aware of to have her account deleted and a definite loss to the community. However everyone needs a break at some point.

Comment: I see. A shame, really ...

Comment: Her reasons is her own, and I will not disclose them myself. If Jeff chooses to he can mention it either by updating my answer or posting his own. We do respect our user's privacy.

Comment: @Downvoter - cause she was a friendly person, always ready to help. @Diago - agree. Personal should be left exactly that - personal.

Comment: @ldigas: I think Downvoter's question was "Why did she want to be deleted?"

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38391/high-reputation-users-having-trouble-understanding-super-user

Comment: @Ether Actually interestingly not at all. She was actually one of the more active high rep users.

Comment: @Diago - in view of one of the topics in Ether's link, and  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39523/terminology-issue-of-computer-related-questions is there hope that one of the most popular close reasons will be rewritten as something more sensible? As one of users who should vote for closing questions more often, I do have a problem with it, since as it stands now, it is written in a way that it allows questions that for example, you, and many others are closing. I know its meaning, but it is not as it is written, as of now.

Comment: @Idigas. It was written after the FAQ change and is correct. The idea is that users should go read the FAQ for more information. So I would say no, it is not going to change. It is too long and big already, the FAQ covers everything in detail.

Comment: @Diago - so what you're saying is that because it is written in the faq, it is justified that we keep confusing close reason descriptions ? Okeeey ... I'll keep that in mind when answering questions in the future. I'll just give a vague notion of the answer, and point them to "that page on google where it is writen in detail". If someone minds I'll just direct them to you.